# How to $add together a subset of elements of an array in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is the problem I want to resolve:

- each document contains an array of 30 integers
- the documents are grouped under a certain condition (not relevant here)
- while grouping them, I want to:

  - add together the 29 last elements of the array (skipping the first one) of each document
  - sum the previous result among the same group, and return it

Data structure is very difficult to change and I cannot afford a migration + I still need the 30 values for another purpose. Here is what I tried, unsuccessfully:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {... some matching query ...}},
    {$project: {total_29_last_values: {$add: ["$my_array.1", "$my_array.2", ..., "$my_array.29"]}}},
    {$group: {
        ... some grouping here ...
        my_result: {$sum: "$total_29_last_values"}
    }}
])
```

Theoretically (IMHO) this should work, given the definition of $add in mongodb documentation, but for some reason it fails:

```
exception: $add only supports numeric or date types, not Array
```

Maybe there is not support for adding together elements of an array, but this seems strange...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please post a sample document from your collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/),

> The $add expression has the following syntax:
>
> { $add: [ `<expression1>`, `<expression2>`, ... ] }
>
> The arguments can be any valid expression as long as they resolve to
>   either all numbers or to numbers and a date.

It clearly states that the `$add` operator accepts only numbers or dates.

`$my_array.1` resolves to an **empty** array. for example, `[]`. (You can always look for a match in  particular index, such as, `{$match:{"a.0":1}}` but cannot derive the value from a particular index of an array. For that you need to use the `$` or the `$slice` operators.This is currently an unresolved issue: [JIRA1](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1831), [JIRA2](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5299))

And the `$add` expression becomes `$add:[[],[],[],..]`.

`$add` does **not** take an array as input and hence you get the error stating that it does not support Array as input.

What you need to do is:

- `Match` the documents.
- `Unwind` the my_array field.
- `Group` together based on the `_id` of each document to get the sum
  of all the elements in the array skipping the first element.
- `Project` the summed field for each grouped document.
- Again `group` the documents based on the condition to get the sum.

Stage operators:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{}}, // condition
{$unwind:"$my_array"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "first_element":{$first:"$my_array"},
         "sum_of_all":{$sum:"$my_array"}}},
{$project:{"_id":"$_id",
           "sum_of_29":{$subtract:["$sum_of_all","$first_element"]}}},
{$group:{"_id":" ",  // whatever condition
         "my_result":{$sum:"$sum_of_29"}}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, I had to tweak it a little bit to the actual structure of my documents. Plus, I didn't know that `$my_array.1` resolved to an array with one element...

Comment: @getmax0 It actually returns an empty array, not with elements. It is currently an unresolved open issue. Have updated that particular point in my answer.